# Visual Studio 2015 + Windows 10 - не работает кнопка табуляции

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

После установки на Windows 10 VS2015 не работает вставка отступа по кнопке Tab. При нажатии в редакторе кода - начинает прокручивать по записям Code Lens для методов.

Скринкаст: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJVOw0pNbQ4

При попытке назначить клавишу - тоже не удается, "прокручивает" по кнопкам. Действие InsertTab назначено почему-то только Windows Forms дизайнеру и Reports дизайнеру. Другие клавиши назначаются нормально.

Скринкаст: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7ATQMcTdd4

Проблема не в клавиатуре, везде кроме VS2015 работает. Проблема воспроизвелась сперва на рабочем компьютере VS2015, потом после обновления винды до 10-ой - и на домашнем. Студия чистая, без дополнительных расширений. Студия и винда лицензионные везде, установлены из оригинальных образом MSDN.
Как можно восстановить нормальное поведение? Невозможно работать без отступов.

**UPD 1:**
Появилось подозрение, что может это связано с аккаунтом MSDN?(через который синхронизируются настройки) Потому что поиском по интернету проблему один в один ни у кого не смог найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо на сервере ms при синхронизации что-то криво записалось. 
Проблема решилась экспортом настроек хоткеев. В настройках через блокнот руками поправил ShortCut-ы, добавил для команды Edit.InsertTab клавишу Tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCGPJ.png

После чего импортировал настройки обратно.